# TypeError: 'SnapResponse' object is not callable

Tags: python, fastapi

I have define a custom exception handler in python 3.10 fastapi `fastapi==0.95.0` app like this:

```
async def too_much_face_exception_handler(request, exc):
    resp = SnapResponse(result="",resultCode="TOO_MUCH_FACE")
    return resp
```

when the code run into this exception handler, the error shows that:

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 237, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 163, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/chat-server/src/routers/snap/photo_process.py", line 23, in photo_upload
    snap_file = process_snap.process_image(save_dirs + file_uniq_name, file)
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/chat-server/src/service/snap/photo/process_snap.py", line 56, in process_image
    reg_face(img_full_path)
  File "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/chat-server/src/tool/graphics/recognize.py", line 29, in reg_face
    raise TooMuchFaceException();
src.common.exception.snap.too_much_face_exception.TooMuchFaceException: too much face

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 436, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 276, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 91, in __call__
    await response(scope, receive, sender)
TypeError: 'SnapResponse' object is not callable
```

this is my `SnapResponse` exception defined:

```
from src.models.chat.rest_response import RestResponse


class SnapResponse(RestResponse):
    def __init__(self, result=None, resultCode=None, uploaded=None):
        super().__init__(result=result, resultCode=resultCode)
        self.uploaded = uploaded
```

am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? and this is the `RestResponse` defined:

```
class RestResponse:
    def __init__(self, msg="", result=None, resultCode="200", statusCode="200"):
        self.msg = msg
        self.result = result if result else {}
        self.resultCode = resultCode
        self.statusCode = statusCode

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            "msg": self.msg,
            "result": self.result,
            "resultCode": self.resultCode,
            "statusCode": self.statusCode
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error:

```
TypeError: 'SnapResponse' object is not callable
```

Means that the `SnapResponse` does not have a `__call__` method, so for example:

```
resp = SnapResponse()
x = resp(data)
```

will raise a `TypeError: 'SnapResponse' object is not callable` because Python does not know how to use the `resp` object as a function.

To fix this, you can either use the `resp` object in a different way or implement an appropriate `__call__` method for the object.